# Why does adding a link to a question as an edit be rejected?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I had come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34971296/segmentation-fault-when-using-strncpy-in-c/34971463#34971463) answer and noticed that the author of the post had not explained what a `C` function called `strncpy` did. Actually, even I did not know it's use, so I searched on the net, and got an answer. I decided that, for future viewers, let me add a link to `strncpy`. I added [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strncpy.htm) link. When I just checked, the progress of the edit, two of the three views were rejects:

> Your suggested edit is pending review.
>
> Alex Jolig reviewed this 8 mins ago: Reject
>
> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.
>
> andrewsi reviewed this 23 mins ago: Reject
>
> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.
>
> Will reviewed this 33 mins ago: Approve
>   (more)

Although, I had edited the question adding the same link, and it got accepted.

So now, I have a question, I added some extra information to the question,  and still it was getting rejected because of some reason.

So, can anyone tell me, is adding a link wasteful, as I did not want to waste the people approving these edits?

**EDIT:** Finally, just now my edit got rejected, as 3 people voted to reject it against two.

Comment: Quoting: 'So, can anyone tell me, is adding a link wasteful, as I did not want to waste the people approving these edits?' <br> should be <br> "So, can anyone tell me, is adding a link wasteful, as I did not want to waste the 'valuable time of' people approving these edits?"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's seems pretty clear that a question fundamentally about a particular operation is going to assume that anyone interested with an answer surrounding a particular intricacy of that answer has a basic idea of what the operation itself is supposed to do.

If someone comes across the question and doesn't even know that the string copy method exists to copy a string, then that question isn't for them.  And if they *still* want to know, it's just a google search away.  That level of information *certainly* doesn't belong in the answer to the question.

That your edit to the question got accepted is an attestment to the fact that no matter how bad an edit is, most reviewers will approve it because they just don't read edits.